# How can I write this code to execute directly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, m2epro

I want to synchronise M2epro inventory with Magento 2.

Tutorial link - https://docs.m2epro.com/display/BestPractice/Programmatic+Possibilities+to+work+with+Extension

M2epro Git Location - https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension

Original Code -

```
    $this->modelFactory instanceof \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory
    $model = $this->modelFactory->getObject('PublicServices\Product\ObjectChange');
    $model->observeProduct(561); 
    $model->applyChanges();
```

How can create above objects ?

Below is my code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//$helperFactory = $objectManager->create('\Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory');
$modelFactory = $objectManager->create('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory');
$model = $modelFactory->create('\Ess\M2ePro\PublicServices\Product\ObjectChange');
$model->observeProduct($id);
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$model->observeProduct($product);
$model->applyChanges();
```

Now here when I am trying to write tutorial code by creating object I am getting error that `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory::create()`

Can anyone please suggest how we can solve this ?

Comment: This is third party module issue, better report to developer and they will provide you the support. Regarding issue, search how to call a helper file and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I just want to know how I can create object using this code as per magento standards? please check update question.

Comment: Magento standards are different than your approach, create a class of your own,  initiate both the helper and model classes in constructor function and create objects of both. then use those objects in your custom functions.

Comment: I dont want to create a class, constructor for this. its just one time php script.

Comment: check the answer and try, if it works then vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a preferred approach but you insist so you should replace the helper code with following:

```
$helperFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Core\Model\Factory\Helper');
$helper = $helperFactory->get('\Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory');
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working. Please check `$this->modelFactory instanceof \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory
    $model = $this->modelFactory->getObject('PublicServices\Product\ObjectChange');
    $model->observeProduct(561); 
    $model->applyChanges();`

Comment: The above solution was to resolve the error you mentioned:
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory::create()

Comment: but it is showing error now `Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Core\Model\Factory\Helper' not found`